# Professor unfairly gives a 0 on a test

Tags: ethics, professorship, grading

My  Professor a day before the test sent an email to the class stating that the test would be open notebook test. I have learning disability and based on it have testing accommodations at my university. The accommodations gives me extra time for my test and therefore I get tested in the testing center. This norm has been followed by all my Professors. However my  professor did not want to follow this norm and wanted me tested with class which wasn't an option for me as I have a class following his class and to take with the class would amount to not availing my extra time accommodations. After lots of effort and getting the counselor to intervene, the professor agrees to let me start the test early and take it in the faculty room.

I start the test with the professor invigilating me and I take out my printed notebook copies and refer them as the test was open notebook. The professor does not make a sound, lets me proceed and after about 15 min leaves the faculty room, returns towards the end of the test ( more than 2 hrs later) and sees me put back my referral notebook back in my book bag. Starts shouting that I cheated and that I would have repercussions.

I am shocked and ask ,what cheating and he says, that you used your notebook. I remind him of his email that said that the test was open notebook. He says that he has changed that ( at the time of me taking my test separately in faculty Rm, the rest of my class is taking the test in the class room  and are told of his changed stance and thus not allowed to use the notebook). I point out to the professor about his email and my use of my notebook stemming from that and the obvious fact that he invigilated and stayed for the first 15  minutes and saw me using notes and neither told me of his changed stance or stopped me, so how was I to know of his changed rules of the test.

The professor admits that he should have told me, but regardless says since I used notebook, I get a zero. I request options to retake the test, do an assignment in place or even take an aggregate score of my rest of the test as an average for this one, but he refuses and says the only option is a zero. I try explaining that even if I do my best in the remaining  three tests with this zero the best I will land is C, but he stands his ground and insists, I deserve a 0.

Consult my counselor and she send me the deans #. Please advise. Did I do something wrong? Am I overlooking a good reason for the professor to make this policy? Is calling the dean the best next step? How do I handle a call to the dean?

Comment: Your next step seems obvious: call the dean and explain the situation. What kind of advice were you looking for here?

Comment: I was looking to get advise from any one  in similar situation, and advise on,  if I am unseeing any wrong on my part ( though logically I see none) and also if any one knows why would the professor be unyielding to give me a chance to change my test score which I got because of no fault of mine ( unsure if Universities do not allow  a grade change once posted).. are the hands of professor tied? ..the options Dean might offer, do not want further negative repercussions because of this no fault of mine situation, I am in...Just legally the options available in this case ...

Comment: I couldn't be bothered to read this, because it's a wall of text. I'd suggest to break it down into paragraphs.

Comment: You need to call the dean as instructed. You could consider asking your counselor to be part of the call. Basically ask her to allow you to make the call from her office so she can answer any questions from the standpoint of the accommodations office. Do this ASAP to get things sorted out before scores get entered in the system.

Comment: I think that counselor is in a much better position to advise you on what policies are at your school.

Comment: I did a fast edit based on OP response in comments.

Comment: One comment here—if the professor changed his mind at the last minute (and it sounds like he did), that's an awful thing to do to students. That shouldn't be lost in the argument here.

Comment: Thxs all.. appreciate all your feedback...

Comment: Not being a lawyer, this is almost certainty discrimination based on disability. Even without malicious intent, this professor made a very bad mistake and should be very apologetic and accommodating of **you** in rectifying this situation. If I were you, I wouldn't put up with any more nonsense from him- escalate to the appropriate authority, and don't agree to take that retest, it won't help you. Also the bit where he sat there and watched you use your notebook without intervening to me shows intent to discriminate. It's rather hard to do that accidentally. I am sorry this happened to you